# Cache file until next page load

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache, cache-control

Is there a way to cache a file until next page load?

I see `expires` and `max-age`, but they require a time delta, which I don't know.

Comment: cache until next page load... isn't it the same as no caching?

Comment: Not quite.  Imagine you use an icon somewhere, and then use the same icon in another section of the page that loads 10 seconds later.  

The second will be another request to your server, if you use no caching.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use JavaScript to add a timestamp to all your external files.

For example if you need to load `http://path/myIcon.png`:

- `var path="http://path/myIcon.png"+"?_ts="+new Date().toString();`
- use the above path for all your myIcon.png images (cached)
- on next page load, the timestamp will be updated and because the url is changed the browser will reload the image